Old hard drive externally connected. Windows detects partitions, but still returns IN/OUT error
I have an old notebook Compaq Armada M300. Last time I have used it was in 2010. It should have Windows XP installed. I am not able to run it. It cannot detect internal hard drive and fails at booting.
Recently, I have connected its HD externally via PATA<->USB to my 2nd notebook with Windows 10. It can detect partitions (File Explorer shows 2 additional drives), but system returns several "An unexpected I/O" errors. Nevertheless, after some time errors stop occuring and File Explorer is able to show that one of the partitions has ~4.5GB of data and 25GB of free space. But still, I cannot access it's files ("An unexpected I/O" errors while trying to open this partition).
I used CHKDSK /v option to list contents, but it only returns that NTFS file system was detected.
Is there still any way to read it?

The drive is likely well into the process of dying. The more you run it, the worse it will be. There are a variety of tricks you can try, but you'll want to be frugal with the amount of time you keep that drive running. Don't run chkdsk or other drive TESTING utilities. You know the drive is dying, you don't need a test to tell you that, and tests stress the drive. Choose a data recovery tool. There are plenty already suggested on this site. Then chill the drive in a freezer, and when you connect it to the computer, keep a cold pack on it.

If the data on this drive is valuable, it would probably be better to send it to a professional data recovery specialist, as they will have additional tools suited for this task.

I suggest that you use a tool like systemrescue (probably old version) and smartctl to see if your disk is SMART capable. If it is, you can read the current health status of the disk and you can appreciate which will be the next steps. It's important not to modify the data on the disk, so that a maximum oh them can be recovered, with tools like ddrescue.

I would suggest not running a drive test tool. We already know the drive is dying, and drive run time should be limited to minimize how far along the path to death we push it.

I wouldn't use any software tool on a failing drive.  I would only do one of two things, the first send in the drive for data recovery, the other if you are unwilling to spend money on data recovery is to use a physical device to clone the HDD. If you use the physical device to clone the HDD then you are throwing away any chance of data recovery use a professional service.

If you do decide to go the DIY ddrescue route to clone the drive as-is(ish) as @Ramhound describes in the unwilling to pay route, I have had ddrescue tie up it's host for weeks even coping with a smallish (<1tb) damaged platter disk.  Expect it to take a long LONG time if the disk is damaged.

@SeñorCMasMas - I was thinking of a HDD cloner, 2 SATA connections, physical button to clone the drive.

Please excuse my lack of precision. Of course, my idea was to make a copy a soon of possible and to work on this copy, but running smartctl at first will give us a coarse idea if this recovery makes sense. Of course, it depends on the value that the stored data has for the owner.

@Ramhound.. for whatever reason I have had situations where the HDD cloner HW failed but I could coax ddrescue through.

@ClaudeFrantz - Every read, every write, every scan of a sector reduces the chances of your ability to clone the drive. As it is your getting I/O errors, the chances you can do anything without fixing the problem with the drive, is extremely low.
